# Rpi Pico Thonny Micropython Setting Up With Rpi4B/Windows PC Problem

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I am currently using ESP-32 in Thonny using micropython. I know that Raspberry Pi pico also uses micro python But There is no option for Raspberry Pi Pico. I am using Thonny 3.2.7.

[image]

Comment: Which OS are you running Thonny on? If Raspberry Pi OS a full update will pull in the latest Thonny. sudo apt update, sudo apt full-upgrade

Comment: @CoderMike ,My Rpi4B buster latest release does not seem to work.  Thonny 3.3.3 does not display the pico option. So I sudo apt update and then sudo apt full-upgrade, then sudo reboot. But I still could not find the pico option. Then I remember my old friend Win10!. I install Thonny in in Win10. Then problem solved. Win 10 Thonny interpreter option has the pico thing.

Comment: This is the screen capture BEFORE I sudo update/upgrade/boot: https://i.imgur.com/eRdWbOM.jpeg. BTW, now  my Chinese Win10 ***Python is 3.7.9***, and About ***Thonny 3.3.3***.

Comment: Now I found that PC Win10 is easy to install and easy to code (Thonny 3.3.3, Python 3.7.9). Going back to Rpi4B, I found the problem with my freshly installed mostly updated buster. I could not find the Pico option in Thonny.  I did sudo/update/full-uugrade/reboot but did not solve the problem. I also tried sudo pip/pip3 install thonny. I finally found the possible problem - ***My thonny is 3.3.0*** not 3.3.3 (Pyhton 3.7.3 not 3.7.9, but I think this is not the problem). Now my question is this: ***How to upgrade Rpi4B buster thonny 3.3.0 to 3.3.3***?

Comment: If you can't update for some reason, then use `MicroPython (generic)` instead.

Comment: @Aivar, Ah, that is very good news. So I can use MicroPython (generic) if I cannot find the Pico option is my Thonny. Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update Your thonny to latest version from https://github.com/thonny/thonny/releases
I am using 3.3.3 and it is showing Raspberry Pi Pico.[image]